# How to build a commenting system on top of my existing posting system in PHP?

Tags: php, mysql

I have a page where the latest status updates by my friends and me are displayed.

The tables involved are statusUpdates, users & friends.

The script I used to pull the necessary data was -

```
$myQuery = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM statusUpdates AS su
    LEFT JOIN friends AS fr ON fr.frContactID = su.authorID
    JOIN (users AS u) ON (u.roll = su.authorID)
    WHERE (fr.frHostID = ".$userLoggedIn['roll']." or su.authorID = ".$userLoggedIn['roll'].")
    GROUP BY su.statusID ORDER BY su.statusID DESC LIMIT 0,15");
```

And I printed the data using this -

```
if (mysql_num_rows($myQuery) == 0) echo "No updates to show";
else
{
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($myQuery))
    {
        // Print $row['statusID'], $row['status'], $row['authorID'], $row['fullName'], $row['userProfileLink'], etc
    }
}
```

Now I am also thinking of incorporating a commenting system.
For that I will be creating a new table **comments** with the following fields - `commentID, targetStatusID, commentorID, comment, commentTimeStamp`

How should I adjust my mysql queries so that the comments for each status update also get printed out in the following way -

```
status1
 - comment1
 - comment2
 - comment3
[text field for new comment to status1]

status2
 - comment1
[text field for new comment to status2]

status3
 [no comments for this post]
[text field for new comment to status3]

status4
 - comment1
 - comment2
[text field for new comment to status4]

[no more posts to show]
```

Please note that -

**commentID** is the primary key.
**targetStatusID** indicates the particular status update on which the comment was made.
**commentorID** is the ID of the person who commented.
**comment** is the actual content.
**commentTimeStamp** shows the time when the comment was made.

By the way, I would like to achieve the whole thing using procedural programming, and *not OOP*.

One of the ways to solve this would be by using a query inside while `($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($myQuery))` to select comments for `$row['statusID']`.

But that would build up the number of queries if I wanted to display many posts.

So what should my approach be?

P.S. I came across similar questions, but none of their answers solved my issue.

Comment: Note that mysql_* functions are depracted and will be removed in future. You should use [mysqli](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) or [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php)

Comment: Yes, and I do intend to get started with PDO once I have completed this particular college project.

Comment: as for your question you can make another kind of function whre you would pass ID of status and then return the comments. You would call this function in your while loop

Comment: I didn't get you. Will you please explain a bit more?

Comment: Note that in the absence of any aggregating functions, the use of GROUP BY is inappropriate. Further, the inclusion of `fr` within your WHERE clause renders your LEFT [OUTER] JOIN as an INNER one.

Comment: I am using `GROUP BY su.statusID` in order to prevent the same "status" from being displayed more than once. This was a problem that I had faced earlier.

Answer (score 0):

I have made an SQLfiddle of your structure. It is not exactly the same but the base data is there.

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/c91cb/16

With this result you can fetch comments to array with explode function. I have managed only to fetch comments with separator and user IDs. If someone could edit the query so it will fetch for him user names it would be good

**Edit**
If no one will edit the query you can explode those IDs and run another query so you will get user names. If you need help just leave comment